# DMS coordinates precision

Tags: openlayers, convert, degrees-minutes-seconds

I'm trying to convert Lat/Lon coordinate to decimal and vice-versa.

Now using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140189/converting-latitude-and-longitude-to-decimal-values.

When I convert `16° 17′ 31″ S 48° 46′ 31″ W` to decimal I got `-48.775277777777774, -16.291944444444447` but I can see the original coordinate from OpenLayers is `-48.775058943087124, -16.291811459160023`.

My steps:

- Take coordinate from map (`-48.775058943087124, -16.291811459160023`).
- Convert to DMS using `hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS( coordinate )`. Got `16° 17′ 31″ S 48° 46′ 31″ W`.
- Convert DMS back to decimal using the function from link above. Result is `-48.775277777777774, -16.291944444444447`.

How can I achieve the correct precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In integer DMS coordinates the **best** precision is a second so `1/60/60` or  0.000277778.

So you need to truncate your results at 3 digits after the decimal so your results do agree.

I went and looked at the [code](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/coordinate.js#L141) which seems as though you can specify the precision of the seconds variable through an option.

```
hdms = ol.coordinate.toStringHDMS( coordinate, 5 )
```

should give a result like `16° 17′ 31.xxxxx″ S 48° 46′ 31.xxxxx″ W`